# Alert em um botao html

Tags: javascript, html

ola, tenho um botão em html e quando clicar nele gostaria de exibir um alert, como faço isso ?

segue o código do botão:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_cadastro" oneclick="cadastro()"/>
```

Comment: `<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_cadastro" onclick="alert('alerta, yay')"/>`

Answer (score 1):

O seu botão está certo, você só precisa alterar o oneclick para onclick.

Veja o código abaixo:

```js
function cadastro(){
  alert('ok');
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_cadastro" onclick="cadastro()"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que sua sintaxe esteja incorreta a chamada da função deve ser "onclick" e não "oneclick" veja:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_cadastro" onclick="cadastro()"/>
```

Verifique se sua função está declarada...

```
<script>
    function cadastro(){
       alert('Sua mensagem aqui!');
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

No HTML

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_cadastro" onclick="cadastro();" />
```

No seu JavaScript

```
function cadastro() {
    alert("Oiii");
}
```

Veja um exemplo funcionando:

https://jsfiddle.net/sq9pc64j/1/

Seu erro é que escreveu onclick errado